# Updating records If ipAddress and playerName match

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment im sending scores and data to my database from my flash game, though every level completed is a new record.

feilds are set out like l1Score,l2Score,l3Score

im trying to figure out how to update records if the field ipAddress and playerName match the current $varibles.

```
 UPDATE highscores SET l2Score = '$l2Score' WHERE ipAddress = "$ipAddress" && playerName = '$playerName'
```

I was thinking somthing along these lines, but could someone point me in the right direction please!

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Is it the query or putting the query into your script? Also SQL uses `AND` not `&&` for 'logical and' operations.

Comment: Everytime a level is completed in the game, it sends out a new record so by level 6 the player has 6 records, i want the first record for that player to update to contain all the data rather then create seperate records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to perform a query to check if there is already a score in place for that user & IP.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE ipAdress = '$ipAdress' AND playerName = '$playerName'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Now, if `$row` is empty then you want to insert a new record, else you want to update a previous record.

```
if($row == "")
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO highscores (l2score, ipAdress, playerName) VALUES ('$l2score', '$ipAdress', '$playerName'";
} else {
   $query = "UPDATE highscores SET l2Score = '$l2Score' WHERE ipAdress = '$ipAdress' AND playerName = '$playerName'";
```

You may need to edit this to fit with the specific query that you need.